# FileNotFoundError when using image.save() from PIL 9.1.1

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to make a python code that outputs an image of the Mandelbrot set and I'm using PIL to handle the image. Everything works fine until I try to save the image. I simplified the code for the sake of simplicity but the error is exactly the same:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.new('RGB', (1, 1), (0, 0, 0))
im.save('output.png', 'PNG')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Documents\coding\python\image.py", line 4, in <module>
    im.save('output.png', 'PNG')
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2297, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'output.png'
```

I've also tried to put the whole path of output.png instead of just 'output.png' but it just gives a different error and also I found on [this website](https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2358/how-to-plot-the-mandelbrot-set/mandelbrot-set) the version with just the name of the file and no one said it didn't work. I've tried to open an existing file and save it too but it didn't work either.

Also, I'm new to PIL so it might be a very simple mistake. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: the code fragment you provided works for me, what version of `Pillow` do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently just updating pip and reinstalling Pillow made it work. Thanks to everyone who got involved :)